# Remove duplicate consecutive tuples from list?

Tags: python

Say, I have a list like below:

```
[(2, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1,0), (2,1), (2, 1)]
```

I want to remove duplicate consecutive tuples. So in above example, it should return:

```
[(2, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: Do you only want to remove consecutive repeats, or all duplicates in the list?

Comment: @James: only consecutive repeats

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

x = [(2, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 1)]
x_grouped = [i for i, j in groupby(x)]
# [(2, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a generator that only yields elements that are not equal to the preceding one:

```
def filter_consecutive_duplicates(it):
    prev = object()  # sentinel object, won't be equal to anything else
    for elem in it:
        if elem != prev:
            yield elem
        prev = elem
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(filter_consecutive_duplicates([(2, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0),(1,0),(2,1), (2, 1)]))
[(2, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[(2, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1,0), (2,1), (2, 1)]
a=[elem for count,elem in enumerate(a) if elem!=a[count-1] or count==0]
```

How about this list comprehension